# Can't get Search Results with Complete Matching

Tags: search-results, advanced-search, title, property

Good day, 
I have the task to create custom search results page for existing list.
The “Title” field in this list can have values like “8841271.050-2017”, “89-11.05-17”, “8841271.082-2019” and another numbers separated by characters “-”,”.”,”/”
I created custom SharePoint Advanced Search Web Part and added property restrictions “Title”.
The Search by Title works fine. But the users can’t understand Search Results.
For example, if they try to find the documents where “Title” contains “030”, the Search Results return documents with “Title” contains “030” and documents with “Title” contains “30”…
For example, one document has Title “8841271.030-2017” and another document has Title “40/276/30-6-1” in Search Results. It doesn’t look right for users.

To correct this I opened «Title» managed property, but the option “Complete Matching” is unavailable for it.

I created DocTitleISM managed property similar “Title” managed property with “Complete Matching” option selected.

I created new template for element displaying.  In my custom Search Results template

'Title':'DocTitleISM',…….

_#=ctx.CurrentItem.DocTitleISM=#_

My next actions:

1. Edit the Advanced Search page
2. Edit the Advanced Search Box webpart
3. In the webparts toolbox, expand the Properties section
4. Copy the text in the Properties textbox to a notepad editor and change it

```
   PropertyDef Name="DocTitleISM" DataType="text" DisplayName="Document Title"/
...

   PropertyRef Name="DocTitleISM" /
```

5. Copy the XML back into the Properties textbox in the webparts toolbox pane
6. Apply the changes to the Advanced Search Box webpart.

But I can’t get any Search Results if I use my DocTitleISM managed property. Maybe I have made some mistake in my manipulations and new managed property doesn’t work?
Correct me, please

Comment: If you have SP onpremise  start Full crawl. For Online you have to reindex that list (List settings > Advanced > Reindex this list).

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint search was designed for documents and words. Your Titles like "8841271.030-2017" contain stop characters and word breakers. You can play with it for weeks and never get the "SQL Style" querying that you seek. You may want to revisit the end user requirements and try to break them of the file name type search. Find other metadata that they can use to discover the documents.

Comment: I set "Complete Matching" by CA and made "Full Crawling".

But I found this problem. Now I can find documents by full Title only. If document has title "sto 7702.002-2009", I can find it by parameter Title contains "sto 7702.002-2009". I haven't search results if I try to find by Title contains "7702.002" or "7702*"

Comment: If I disable " Complete Matching " for Title managed property, I have another problem. In this case, Search doesn’t return results if I try to find document by full title. For example, if I try to find by “sto 7702.002-2009” title value the search returns no results. But if I search for “7702” value, I can see the documents with part “7702” in Title. If “Title” contains “030”, the Search Results return documents with “Title” contains “030” and document with “Title” contains “it 40/276/30-6-1” and it is not right.

Comment: How can I understand this SP search logic? I would like to get results by parameters “sto 7702.002-2009”, “7702.002-2009”, “7702”. And I wouldn’ like to get document with title “it 40/276/30-6-1” when I am searching for “030”.

Comment: Should I create a new topic about SP Search logic?

Comment: You can try, but I am trying to tell you I have been down this road for many years and you will never get this SQL like query logic to work. If you want a SQL query, use SQL.